# Is there a way to hide/un-enable a groupbox if a selected treeview node is a parent?

Tags: vb.net

I need to hide/un-enable a groupbox if a selected tree view item is a parent.
I have tried several things but nothing is working.

This is one thing I tried.

```
    Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

    If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent = True Then
        GroupBox2.Enabled = False
        Panel1.Enabled = False
        GroupBox3.Enabled = False
    Else
        GroupBox2.Enabled = True
        Panel1.Enabled = True
        GroupBox3.Enabled = True
    End If


End Sub
```

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: `If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent = True Then...`? I assume you have `Option Strict Off`...

Comment: What do you mean with _is a parent_? Root `TreeNode` maybe? If so, the root nodes have no parents (null/Nothing) and their `Level` properties return `0`.

Comment: @dr.null . I guess a Root node is what I was thinking was a called parent node. So, do I need something like this? If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Checked = 0 Then

Comment: `If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Level = 0 Then .. End If` OR `If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent Is Nothing .. End If`.

Comment: @dr.null I tried both, but they only un-enables the highest level nodes. I need to un-enable the groupbox if a node has a Parent/Root no matter how deep it is in the tree.

Comment: Then you need `If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent IsNot Nothing Then .. ` disable the groupbox otherwise enable it.

Comment: @dr.null Thank you so much for helping me with this problem. It is working!

Answer (score 1):

For ease of future expansion, you can keep all the controls you want to change in a list, and do this:

```
Private _leafControls As List(Of Control)

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    _leafControls = New List(Of Control)
    _leafControls.Add(Panel1) 
    _leafControls.Add(GroupBox2)
    _leafControls.Add(GroupBox3)
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

    _leafControls.ForEach(Function (x) x.Enabled = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent Is Nothing)

End Sub
```

Add more controls to the list in the constructor, to expand the behavior to other controls

If there will only ever be 3 controls, perhaps hard coding them is simpler:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
    GroupBox2.Enabled = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent Is Nothing
    Panel1.Enabled = GroupBox2.Enabled
    GroupBox3.Enabled = GroupBox2.Enabled
End Sub
```

You don't need to test something to be equal to a boolean and then set booleans inside the If, you can just use the boolean you get from running the test:

```
'enable groupbox 2 when the selected node has no parent
GroupBox2.Enabled = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent Is Nothing
```

(this logic has come from the comments; the logic requested in the session title is different):

```
'disable groupbox when treenode has children(is a parent)
'=enable groupbox when node has no children
GroupBox2.Enabled = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count = 0
```

Please name your controls something better that GroupBox2, Panel1